# How do i add two listfragment in my app

Tags: android

I have an app which displays first list using below code. How do i display on more list on click of any list item from below code. Please help me with an example code.

```
public class MyListFragment1 extends ListFragment {

    String[] VideoSetup ={
            "Properties", 
            "Color Control", 
            "Tint", 
            "3D Depth",
            "3D Format", 
            "Dynamic Backlight", 
            "Mode", 
            "Cache ID",

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                VideoSetup);
        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(), 
                getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Fragment2 frag = (Fragment2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    }




}
```

I am not really sure of doing this. I am very new to android.

Comment: You can use ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must write second ListFragment. Similarly.

Then, in onListItemClick() method of first Fragment you can write something like this:

```
Fragment2 frag = (Fragment2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

activity.getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

This is your fragment container - /res/layout/activity_main.xml. It is empty. Bind it with MainActivity.class by setContentView(R.layout.activity_main):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
</RelativeLayout>
```

After that you have to add new first fragment on fragment container like described above.

Then, in onListItemClick(...) method of first fragment you have to create new second fragment and replace first.

Comment: The above code does what i wanted to do , now i have a problem which is very silly guess. Please help me with this too.
I have another fragment with a list in it. When i launch the activity by default it shows that list. I wanted to show the list in second fragment on click of list item in first fragment.