# Start another Fragment on click from a list in listfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am able to start another fragment using on item selected from list fragment. In second fragment i have a list view which I want only to be displayed when list item is clicked from first fragment. But I am getting the list view items in second fragment as soon as I start the activity.

```
public class MyNewFragment extends ListFragment{


    String[] newLists ={
            "hey", 
            "hello Control", 
            "what", 
            "3D gone",
            "chindiyaa", 
            "hat sala", 
            "Heheheheh", 
            "chal nikal",

    };

    /*@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.justatestlayout, container, false);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment_layout, container, false);
            ListView lv2 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView3);
            lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newLists));             
            return view;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                newLists);
        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: `MyNewFragment` is the first or second fragment?

Comment: It is the second fragment .  First fragment is shown in below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438844/how-do-i-add-two-listfragment-in-my-app/18440277?noredirect=1#18440277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListShown%28boolean%29) says the ListView in a ListFragment will only be visible if the Adapter is set to the ListView by calling `setListAdapter(adapter)`. So have f.e. a boolean flag to indicate if a ListItem was clicked and if this flag is true load your Adapter.

Edit:

I forgot about the Progress indicator while the ListView is empty. There is no way to hide it without showing the ListView items.

Here's another approach: Set the visibility of your Fragment to GONE/INVISIBLE. If your ListItem is clicked change it to VISIBLE.

Comment: Thanks , it looks really fine but there's loading animation constantly displayed . Any idea why is that?

Comment: I could disable the loading bar by adding this is my fragments
@Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  setListShown(true);
 }

Comment: Nice to know. In the past this call was buggy. Hope that it is fixed now.